# Как изменить значения в матрице?

Tags: java, матрицы

Задана матрица целых чисел каждый элемент которой или 0 или 1.
Пытался сделать инвентирование значений, т.е 0=>1 и 1=>0. Но что-то не работает

```
public class ex3 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int arr [][]= {{0,0,1} ,
                   {0,1,0} ,
                   {1,0,0}};
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {

        if(arr[i][i]==1){
            arr[i][i]=0;
        }
        if(arr[i][i]==0){
            arr[i][i]=1;
        }
        System.out.println(arr[i][i]);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема в том, что Вы создали двумерный массив, но прошлись только по элементах, которые являются массивами, не включая внутренние елементы самих массивов.

```
int[][] array = {
    {1, 0, 0},
    {0, 1, 1},
    {0, 1, 0}
};

for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++) {
        array[i][j] = (array[i][j] == 1) ? 0 : 1;
        System.out.print(array[i][j] + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Вывод:

```
0 1 1 
1 0 0 
1 0 1
```

Comment: @Игорь, не кажеться,а так оно и будет. Это уже зависит от условия задачи. Я сделал по примеру, который был в вопросе.

Answer (score 0):

Можно еще через for...each.

```
public class Arr{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int[][] array = {
            {1, 0, 0},
            {0, 1, 1},
            {0, 1, 0}
        };

        for(int[] dim: array){
            for(int i = 0; i < dim.length; i++){
                dim[i] = (dim[i] == 1) ? 0 : 1;
                System.out.print(dim[i] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```